# FetchAll method in Social Engine not working for large number of records

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, socialengine

I have a site built in Social Engine.It uses zend frame work AND Mysql as backend

I am fetching  records using fetchAll() method .

I am able to fetch records about 30000 .

But if i try to fetch more than 30000 records, it show a blank screen that is some error.

I am sure  that error is not related to the data  because i can fetch all these data using query in phpmyadmin  tool

What may be the issue.?
Is it any memory issue in php  or mysql ?

Anyone have idea?

Answer (score 0):

it's a memory issue.
do not fetch that much records using `fetchAll()`
use `while($row = $stmt->fetch())` loop instead

Also you may consider selecting lesser amount of rows

Comment: Thanks for the comment.Due to some reason, i can't change fetchAll() in all my pages.So next option is change the memory size.So which memory variable should i change

Comment: Oh, if you want to kill your server instead of changing few lines of code - you are surely welcome

Comment: Actually , in my situation, iam not using fetchAll() on direct query .It using on core model object

Comment: its USING big amounts of memory is a big issue. Walking on the edge consuming all the available memory on the every call already killing your server, even if you don't hit the limit

Comment: Actually , in my situation, iam not using fetchAll() on direct query .It using on core model object

Comment: Actually, in such edge cases like this, one have to fix the code, not adding crutches